# Command handling for Discord Bot

Tags: java, string, parsing, kotlin

I'm working on a Discord Bot for moderation. I use JDA library. I'm currently stuck at command handling.

There are 4 command scenarios:

```
".ban <@302390080104955904> advertising"
".ban <@!302390080104955904> advertising"
".ban 302390080104955904 advertising"
".ban et advertising"
```

When bot receives the command I substring the command and prefix.

In first scenario I want to extract the ID "302390080104955904" and remove it from the string so I just get the reason

Second scenario is same as first but it has an exclamation mark after @

In third scenario I just have to extract the ID and remove it

And in the last scenario I only have to get the user's name supplied and search for the user.

I tried to implement this multiple times but I always failed.
Any ideas on how I can make this work

EDIT: I accept both Kotlin and Java answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sub>I'm assuming you have a technique for separating the command from the command content already - if I misunderstood that part, please correct me.</sub>

Once you get the command itself separated from the content, you'll end up with a string similar to:

```
val commandContent = "<@!302390080104955904> advertising";
```

From here, you'll need to split it up:

```
val cache = commandContent.split(" ", limit=2);
```

What you have now is an array with up to two in size.

From there, parse it slightly further to keep your data clear:

```
// Note: I haven't implemented any safety. If you get an unexpected size, you'll need to handle that yourself
val target = cache[0];
val reason = cache[1];
```

from here, you can use regex. Before I get into the code, let me explain the regex:

```
<?        - Attempt to match an opening bracket
@?        - Attempt to find @
!?        - Attempt to find !
([0-9]+)  - Constant: find a group of numbers
>?        - Attempt to find a closing bracket
```

This also helps filter out usernames in the `username#discriminator` format - any non-number character will recognize the String as not an ID. You can also play around with it on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/GNmKhe/1).

From here, you can set up the matching:

```
val regex = """<?@?!?([0-9]+)>?""".toRegex()
fun getMatch(target: String) : String? = regex.matchEntire(target)?.groups?.get(1)?.value
```

`getMatch(target)` returns null if the ID isn't found, and the ID as a String otherwise.

Now, all you need to do is call the method and do whatever you want:

```
val match = getMatch(target); 
if (match != null) {
    // You have the UID. 
} else {
    // You have a username. Use `target` to retrieve the user ID. 
}
```

While this works, there's something you **need** to keep in mind: when it comes to usernames, your example only included the username *without* the discriminator. If your bot joins a large enough server, and you i.e. iterate over users to find one with a matching username, you'll likely find yourself banning the wrong person, or banning everyone with that username if you forget to break the loop.

If I were you, I'd check for the presence of `#[0-9]{4}` either by using regex, or splitting the username at `#` and making sure you get two parts, and that the second part only consists of digits:

```
val split = target.split("#")
if (split.size != 2) // Fail
if (split[1].toLongOrNull() == null || split[1].length != 4 || split[1].contains("-")) // fail - non-number long, invalid discriminator (discriminators are always 4 digits), or negative discriminator
```

The discriminators are in the range `0001` to `9999`. Either way, it always has 4 digits. Note that the conversion to a long loses any prefixed 0's, so stick to strings for validation. And if you run this validation, you need to run it against the username, **not** the nickname (nicknames can contain `#`, usernames can't)